# How to enable or disable a button while the user is typing in Vue Ui-select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ui-select

I have a `ui-select` option in vue that allows the user to select or type its desired search item. Please see picture below:

[image]

This is it's back-end:

```
<ui-select 
    v-model="groupName"
    has-search
    @input="checkEvent()"
></ui-select>
```

So, while the user is typing in the search box of the `<`ui-select>`, I want to call the method`checkEvent()`:

```
checkEvent(){
    console.log("You've called me");
}
```

But this one is only executed on load of the page, and when I try to type, it's not executed. Am I doing it the right way? I really need someone's help here, so stuck on this. I'm using [Keen-UI](https://josephuspaye.github.io/Keen-UI/#/ui-select) by the way.

Answer (score 0):

`input` is emitted only when you select an option. You should listen for `query-change` instead:

```
<ui-select 
    v-model="groupName"
    has-search
    @query-change="checkEvent"
    @input="checkEvent()"
></ui-select>
```